# Обработка голоса

Tags: java, c++, аудио

Имеется `запись_голоса.ogg`, необходимо программным способом наложить какие-нибудь эффекты, чтобы на выходе получился обработанный файл.
Есть готовые библиотеки или сторонние программы, которыми через консоль или как-то ещё можно накладывать готовые эффекты? Например, эффект гелия, грубый голос или что-то ещё.
Если нет готовых библиотек/программ для этого, с готовыми шаблонами, то в какую сторону гуглить, чтобы разобраться конкретно с этим и самому обработать файл нужным образом? В таком случае, интересуют способы на Java/C++.
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: http://www.beadsproject.net/ - первый обработчик звуков, который нашел. А вообще, проще всего "вскрыть" готовую программу для обработки голосов, пусть даже это будет Android-приложение, достать от туда код с обработкой и скопипастить себе.

Comment: @RostislavDugin знаю я, как выглядит такой код, и даже смотреть на него не очень хочется :) Да и неправильно это как-то. Неужели нет нормальной программки, которую можно через консоль, например `programname -input file.ogg -effect helium -output file_new.ogg` ?

Comment: Если найдете — будет! А по другому сложнее. Это самый простой способ. Берете код, рефакторите и корректируете под себя. Если выйдет, может можно выпросить приложение с хорошим кодом и документацией (если такое бывает...).

Comment: Некогда развлекался с SunVox в этом направлении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть один довольно удобный, простой, кроссплатформенный проект, с открытыми сорсами и написанный на двух языках для удобства: [Sonic](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic).

Пример кода можно увидеть в моём ответе [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683145/sourcedataline-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-wav-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB).