# SourceDataLine сохранить в wav-файл

Tags: java, wav

Нашел способ обрабатывать записи голоса, решил использовать [этот](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic) проект.
Столкнулся с проблемой: 
На Java всё работает отлично, но я не могу разобраться, как сохранить результат в wav-файл. Вот код:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {

    // Новые параметры
    float speed = 1.0f;
    float pitch = 0.8f;
    float rate = 0.75f;
    float volume = 7.0f;
    boolean emulateChordPitch = false;
    int quality = 1;

    // Читаем файл
    AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("test.wav"));
    AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
    int sampleRate = (int) format.getSampleRate();
    int numChannels = format.getChannels();
    SourceDataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format,
            ((int) stream.getFrameLength() * format.getFrameSize()));
    SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

    // Файл воспроизводится
    line.open(stream.getFormat());
    line.start();
    runSonic(stream, line, speed, pitch, rate, volume, emulateChordPitch, quality,
            sampleRate, numChannels);
    line.drain();
    line.stop();
}
```

И метод **runSonic**:

```
private static void runSonic(
        AudioInputStream audioStream,
        SourceDataLine line,
        float speed,
        float pitch,
        float rate,
        float volume,
        boolean emulateChordPitch,
        int quality,
        int sampleRate,
        int numChannels) throws IOException {
    Sonic sonic = new Sonic(sampleRate, numChannels);
    int bufferSize = line.getBufferSize();
    byte inBuffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    byte outBuffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    int numRead, numWritten;

    sonic.setSpeed(speed);
    sonic.setPitch(pitch);
    sonic.setRate(rate);
    sonic.setVolume(volume);
    sonic.setChordPitch(emulateChordPitch);
    sonic.setQuality(quality);
    do {
        numRead = audioStream.read(inBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        if (numRead <= 0) {
            sonic.flushStream();
        } else {
            sonic.writeBytesToStream(inBuffer, numRead);
        }
        do {
            numWritten = sonic.readBytesFromStream(outBuffer, bufferSize);
            if (numWritten > 0) {
                // Если закомментировать следующую строчку, файл не будет воспроизводиться
                line.write(outBuffer, 0, numWritten);
                // По логике, в outBuffer должны храниться байты результата
                // Выводил на экран - много разных массивов размером 96000
                // Их нужно объединить и записать в файл, или как?
            }
        } while (numWritten > 0);
    } while (numRead > 0);
}
```

В примерах кода привел комментарии. 
Суть: результативный файл воспроизводится, а мне нужно, чтобы воспроизведения не было, а была лишь запись в файл. Думаю, исходники проекта нет смысла приводить, и что-то нужно изменить/добавить в коде, который я привел. Спасибо заранее.

---

**UPDATE:**
В цикле после `line.write` каждый раз добавлял outBuffer к существующему массиву байтов:

```
public byte[] concat(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    int aLen = a.length;
    int bLen = b.length;
    byte[] c = new byte[aLen + bLen];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);
    return c;
}
```

затем записал его в файл:

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, byte_array);
```

и попытался сконвертировать этот файл в wav, как описано [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569304/android-how-can-i-write-byte-to-wav-file). 
До этого момента ошибок нет, массивы склеиваются правильно (проверено), файл тоже записывается, и так далее. Даже wav рабочий. Однако не без косяков: Прослушать пример: [линк.wav](https://petersamokhin.com/ruso.wav). Причём, самое странное, что при одних настройках всё нормально, а при других как на приведенной записи - какие-то участки записи повторяются. Почему так и как можно исправить?

---

**UPDATE:**
Попробовал записать этот же результативный byte[] в wav, но уже другим способом, результат получается абсолютно аналогичный. [Второй способ тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991391/saving-audio-byte-to-a-wav-file).

Использую AudioFormat от исходного файла, то есть различий в rate/sampleSize/каналах быть не может. В чем же проблема? При воспроизведении всё хорошо, потом этот результативный массив записывается в файл, и вылазят косяки. Если в line.write использовать inBuffer, то, логично, воспроизводиться будет первоначальный файл, также если и записывать в файл inBuffer, то будет записана исходная запись, но с тем же косяком на тех же моментах. Если же изначально в "новых параметрах" rate указать именно 1.3f (не больше и не меньше), то получается нормально, только после слов чувствуются паузы, как будто запись прерывается (???). Если менять именно этот параметр, косяк лишь усугубляется.

---

Вся результативная запись (которая и воспроизводится) разбита на блоки по 96 кб. Их же я все и объединяю в один файл. Я попробовал сохранять каждый блок в отдельный файл и обнаружил, что есть идентичные wav-файлы, которые получаются из абсолютно разных массивов. Я вычислял специально повторяющиеся блоки, смотрел на массивы байтов, и в начале, и в середине, и в конце, они все различаются. Однако файлы идентичны абсолюнто: открыл через текстовый редактор их, разница есть в первых нескольких строках, и всё. Так вот я не понимаю вообще, в чем дело. В таком случае, придется искать костыли, сравнивать эти кучи wav-файлов, удалять повторяющиеся, а потом склеивать в один файл. Но это слишком уж костыльно, да и как сравнивать wav-файлы, тоже не очень понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Моя невнимательность: при воспроизведении, в `line` я передавал **numWritten** байт из `outBuffer`, а при записи в файл передавал массив полностью. 
Пример рабочего варианта записи в файл:

```
            // Запись в массив
            byte[] result = new byte[0];
            do {
                numRead = stream.read(inBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                if (numRead <= 0) {
                    sonic.flushStream();
                } else {
                    sonic.writeBytesToStream(inBuffer, numRead);
                }
                do {
                    numWritten = sonic.readBytesFromStream(outBuffer, bufferSize);
                    if (numWritten > 0) {
                        // concat - мой костыльный метод для склеивания 
                        // одного массива с первыми n элементами другого массива
                        result = concat(result, outBuffer, numWritten);
                    }
                } while (numWritten > 0);
            } while (numRead > 0);

            // Запись в файл
            ByteArrayInputStream b_in = new ByteArrayInputStream(result);
            AudioInputStream stream_result = new AudioInputStream(b_in, format, result.length);
            AudioSystem.write(stream_result, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File(result_file_path));
```